# view as html feature

Tags: php, linux

hey i am maintaining a site on a linux server. its in php. the registered members can upload files and download it. But I want to implement " view as html " feature (as google do it). Can anyone help me out..

Comment: i want foir .doc files and linux version is RHEL 4

Answer (score 2):

You didn't specify what file type so I will assume you meant PDFs. There are a number of linux based utilities to convert a PDF to HTML. Check out [Poppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/). Your PHP would run the `pdf2html` command using [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) (or a similar function) and save the HTMl to a folder where you could grab it and send it to any client asking for the HTML version.

If you were looking to convert from Word to HTML (again, you didn't specify what file type) take a look at [wvWare](http://wvware.sourceforge.net/index.html).